# How to make Pinta save .svg files?

Tags: codecs, svg, pinta

Is there a codec pack or something that lets me save SVG and XPM files with Pinta???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinta is a raster editing program, and not a vector program, so you can't save to SVG with it.

I don't know what underlying libraries it uses, but if it doesn't support saving to XPM, perhaps you should file a bug report against it upstream, stating that XPM is not supported.

Comment: Alright then. Is there an alternative capable of saving to SVG and XPM that has all the same features?

Comment: No. SVG and XPM are fundamentally different things. If you want to draw vector images you can use Inkscape and then export to XPM if you want (though I don't know why you'd want XPM at all).